# Entitlement mediator in wso2esb

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm using Entitlement mediator in wso2esb 4.8.0 and wso2is 4.1.0 to authenticate and authorise with WSO2ESB and WSO2IS.For this implementation i have follow [http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/authentication-and-authorization-with-wso2esb-and-wso2is/](http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/authentication-and-authorization-with-wso2esb-and-wso2is)

but while executing the proxy with username:admin and password:admin sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception occurs as:

```
    PassThroughHttpSSLListener System may be unstable: HTTPS ListeningIOReactor encountered a runtime exception : sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DOMAIN_PARAMS_INVALID
    java.lang.RuntimeException: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DOMAIN_PARAMS_INVALID
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1028)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:508)
.
.
```

I don't understand why i'm receiving this error. I have set up the correct URL as `https://localhost:9443/services` and "admin" user-pass.What is exact problem?let me know..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OpenJDK? If please check, [this](http://shickys.blogspot.com/2012/11/addressing-openjdk-bug-with-ssl-on.html) seems to be an issue with openJDK. As I know, WSO2 product are not recommended to run with OpenJDK. I guess,  it is better to try out with Oracle or IBM JDK